# Django error: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: django, save

I have been following along with the book Practical Django Projects. Very nice book, but it seem to have a lot of bugs. Luckily this website has some fixes: `https://bitbucket.org/philgyford/practical-django-projects/src`. My latest error is: `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'`

The original code was:

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField()
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    code = models.TextField()
    highlighted_code = models.TextField(editable=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    objects = managers.SnippetManager()
    tags = TagField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        if not self.id:
            self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.updated_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.description_html = markdown(self.description)
        self.highlighted_code = self.highlight()
        super(Snippet, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('cab_snippet_detail', (), { 'object_id': self.id })

    def highlight(self):
        return highlight(self.code,
                         self.language.get_lexer(),
                         formatters.HtmlFormatter(linenos=True))

# See http://blog.sveri.de/index.php?/categories/2-Django
tagging.register(Snippet, tag_descriptor_attr='etags')
```

I changed the save method (trying to get rid of the error) to:

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if not 'force_insert' in kwargs:
         kwargs['force_insert'] = False
      if not 'force_update' in kwargs:
         kwargs['force_update'] = False
      # del kwargs['force_insert']
      if not self.id:
         self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
      self.updated_date = datetime.datetime.now()
      self.description_html = markdown(self.description)
      self.highlighted_code = self.highlight()
      super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I even tried uncommenting the # del bit, which also does not help. Im'm using Django 1.3.1. Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version of your save override should be fine, though I would get rid of the two `if` statements and the `del` line.

If it still doesn't work, make sure you the development server is actually reloading the models.py file. The quickest way is to CTRL+C the running one and then call `python manage.py runserver` again. Although it shouldn't matter, you might want to also get rid of `models.pyc` as well (compiled version of models.py), just to be extra sure that the new code is running.

While Practical Django Projects is an excellent book overall, it's *very* outdated at this point. You might want to look for newer resources to learn from.

Comment: Just fixed it myself, turns out I needed to do it on the bookmarks model as well, since that uses the snippet model.